# NopCommerce Category Navigation Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am trying to edit this category navigation view. What I need is this:

- We do not want to see all main categories or all sub categories as well.
- When I click a Main Category (ParentCategoryId = 0), I should see only this one and it's sub categories.
- When I click one of this sub categories, this sub category should be main category, and this time I should see it's sub categories only.

For ex, navigation system works like this right now:

- Women (selected)

  - Bag
  - Top
  - Dress
- Sound Systems
- Home Decoration
- Gardening

or

- Women

  - Bag
  - Top (selected)

    - Tshirt
    - Sweatshirt
    - Tunic
  - Dress
  - Jeans
  - Suit
- Sound Systems
- Home Decoration
- Gardening

What we want is that:

- Women (selected)

  - Bag
  - Top
  - Dress
  - Jeans
  - Suit

or

- Top (selected)

  - Tshirt
  - Sweatshirt
  - Tunic

    ```
        @model CategoryNavigationModel
    @using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
    @using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
    @functions{
        public bool BreadCrumbContainsCurrentCategoryId(CategorySimpleModel category)
        {
            if (Model.CurrentCategoryId == 0)
                return false;

            if (category.Id == Model.CurrentCategoryId)
                return true;

            foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
            {
                if (BreadCrumbContainsCurrentCategoryId(subCategory))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
    @helper RenderCategoryLine(CategorySimpleModel category)
    {
    var _categoryService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<Nop.Services.Catalog.ICategoryService>();
    // additional check on whether to set an active class on the parents of the current categories and above. Meaning all categories from the 
    // breadcrumb will have an "active" class
    bool active = false;
    if (category.Id == Model.CurrentCategoryId || category.SubCategories.Count(BreadCrumbContainsCurrentCategoryId) > 0)
    {
        active = true;
    }
        <li class="@(active ? "active" : "inactive")">
            @if (category.ParentCategoryId == Model.CurrentCategoryId || category.Id == Model.CurrentCategoryId)
            { 
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })">@category.Name
                    @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
                    {
                        <text> </text>@T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
                    }
                </a>
            }
            @{
                if (category.Id == Model.CurrentCategoryId ||
                    category.SubCategories.Count(BreadCrumbContainsCurrentCategoryId) > 0)
                {
                    if (category.SubCategories.Count > 0)
                    {
                        <ul class="sublist">
                            @foreach (var subCategory in category.SubCategories)
                            {
                                @RenderCategoryLine(subCategory)
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                }
            }
        </li>
    }
    @if (Model.Categories.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="block block-category-navigation">
            <div class="title">
                @if (Model.CurrentCategoryId == 1 || Model.CurrentCategoryId == 3 || Model.CurrentCategoryId == 4 || Model.CurrentCategoryId == 5)
                {
                    <strong>@T("Categories")</strong>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="event.preventDefault(); history.back(1);"><strong><< Geri Dön</strong></a>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="listbox">
                <ul class="list">
                    @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        @RenderCategoryLine(category)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    ```

My code is something like this, but there is a problem. Code is not working when selected category has no sub categories. On this situation it must do something like this:

PS: Sweatshirt has no sub categories.

- Top

  - Tshirt
  - Sweatshirt (selected)
  - Tunic

Instead it shows something like this:

- Sweatshirt (selected)

I'd hope I can explain myself. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Tough to understand, *When I click a Main Category* So you have only one main category in your project?

Comment: *What we want is that:* It's unclear part...